# Is it possible to change the Azure PIM notification event?

Tags: azure, pim

Usually, you manage the Approval workflow with an E-Mail notification to grand the Resource Access for a current User.

Is it possible to change the notification method? So I'm not forced to use an E-Mail for the Approval?

Comment: Found an easy way myself - I set up a slack webhook and mail rule that forwards PIM emails to this channel, works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to create a customised approval flow using Azure Logic Apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) which allows you to choose different methods of notification. You may need to create a script or two to achieve exactly what you want (particularly in regards to granting permissions to resources) but nothing too complicated.

**Update**

I found the following page which may further assist in achieving what you need.

https://gotoguy.blog/2018/09/15/create-your-own-azure-ad-pim-app-with-powerapps-and-flow-using-microsoft-graph/

It is possible to connect PowerApps with Azure Logic Apps with the connectors available.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but I'm not sure if I can follow your idea correctly. I'm not aware that Logic Apps support any way to implement a connection to PIM. But I would love to if you can correct me here, so I can learn something.

Comment: I've updated the answer with further information. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my problem is the Blog article shows a way to use the Graph API to give certain users a role, but he doesn't get deeper in the notification and approval steps. I think he just skips the E-mail notification at all and approves the request by default. He doesn't have any request verification.